# python print funcition is not working with a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a dice game where you print out a dice face(I am a beginner)
and it has to have 2 classes. A class called DiceGame. it has a method called play, which shows the die face. There is also a class called Die. It has an attribute called face, which holds the face image. There is a method called roll, which randomly sets the face.

```
import random

class Die(object):

    def __init__ (self, face =None, faceValue = None):
        self.face = face
        self.faceValue = faceValue
    def roll(self):
        for c in range(1,2):
            random.randint(1,2)
            if random == '1':
                self.face = (' ------\n|      |\n|   o  |\n|      |\n ------')
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.face)
class DiceGame(Die):
    def play(self):
        print(self.face)
go = DiceGame(Die)
print(go.play)
```

The output is

```
bound method DiceGame.play of <__main__.DiceGame object at 0x7fd060db0358>>
```

It should print the die face. (I am new to stack overflow. Not sure why my code is formatted like that.)

Comment: If you want to call `play`, you need `go.play()`, with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code:

1. On line `go = DiceGame(Die)` class Die will be sent as face into constructor. Try `go = DiceGame()` instead.
2. You do not call method play on line `print(go.play)`. Try `go.play()` instead.
3. `random.randint(1,2)` return integer object. Comparison with '1' would always result in False.
4. In your code, you do not actually roll.

Fixed code:

```
import random
class Die(object):
    def __init__(self, face=None, faceValue=None):
        self.face = face
        self.faceValue = faceValue

    def roll(self):
        self.faceValue = random.randint(1, 6)
        if self.faceValue == 1:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '|      |\n'
                '|   o  |\n'
                '|      |\n'
                ' ------')
        elif self.faceValue == 2:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '| o    |\n'
                '|      |\n'
                '|    o |\n'
                ' ------')
        elif self.faceValue == 3:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '| o    |\n'
                '|   o  |\n'
                '|     o|\n'
                ' ------')
        elif self.faceValue == 4:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                '|      |\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                ' ------')
        elif self.faceValue == 5:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                '|   o  |\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                ' ------')
        elif self.faceValue == 6:
            self.face = (
                ' ------\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                '| o   o|\n'
                ' ------')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.face)


class DiceGame(Die):
    def play(self):
        self.roll()
        print(self.face)


go = DiceGame()
go.play()
```

Alternative roll method could be:

```
    def roll(self):
        self.face_value = random.randint(1, 6)
        self.face = u"⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅"[self.face_value-1]
```

but then you will probably need to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as first line of your code to denote coding.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jan, although I would change the method `play` in the DiceGame class to return `self.face` and not just print it. Instead I would `print(go.play())`.

```
import random

class Die(object):

    def __init__ (self, face =None, faceValue = None):
        self.face = face
        self.faceValue = faceValue
    def roll(self):
            self.faceValue = random.randint(1, 6)
            if self.faceValue == 1:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '|      |\n'
                    '|   o  |\n'
                    '|      |\n'
                    ' ------')
            elif self.faceValue == 2:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '| o    |\n'
                    '|      |\n'
                    '|    o |\n'
                    ' ------')
            elif self.faceValue == 3:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '| o    |\n'
                    '|   o  |\n'
                    '|     o|\n'
                    ' ------')
            elif self.faceValue == 4:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    '|      |\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    ' ------')
            elif self.faceValue == 5:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    '|   o  |\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    ' ------')
            elif self.faceValue == 6:
                self.face = (
                    ' ------\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    '| o   o|\n'
                    ' ------')
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.face)
class DiceGame(Die):
    def play(self):
        self.roll()
        return self.face

go = DiceGame()
print(go.play())
```